# Best way to typecast uint256 to uint128 in ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js

assuming a slot has multiple data like `uint128,uint128` packed into it, how do you retrieve these individual values when inspecting that slot using ethersjs

Comment: Bitwise `&`-ing with a mask or using a right-shift `>>`? :-)

Comment: how would right-shifts work?

Comment: ha.. this makes sense
so if i have `uint256 a=11222333;`
and i try to typecast to uint32

i just have to do `a & type(uint32).max`
which works fine

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

a bitwise `&` works perfectly

in ethersjs

```js
//uint256
const x = BigNumber.from(434343434)
//note that y is gotten with type(uint32).max
const y = BigNumber.from(4294967295)
//typecasting to uint32
const y = x.and(UINT32MAX)
```